# When ExpressJS serves API only, what template engine do I have to choose

Tags: node.js, express

I am studying NodeJS and React front-end. And I want to test what I have learned by making a web page.

I want to create two servers: back-end server to provide API, front-end server to manipulate data by communicating with back-end server through AJAX.

In backend server, I will use NodeJS(expressJS). I have been reading below link to install expressJS server.

[enter link description here](https://expressjs.com/ko/starter/generator.html)

but I am stuck on choosing which template engine do I use. Since I want my back-end server to be provider for just only API - besides, I am not sure what API means correctly, I guess it is for manipulating data throguh AJAX

So simply my question is,

**What template engine do I have to adopt in my back-end server?**

Comment: Dont use any. Just JSON format would be better to manage backend errors from React

Comment: None, you just write `res.json({hello: 'world'});`

Comment: Voting to close as `Off Topic - Asking to recommend a tool`.

Comment: @Narm OK, I got answers by others, I am gonna remove this post.

Comment: If this question was changed to "Do I need a template engine for a json api in expressjs?" (and the body changed accordingly) then this could be quite useful for people in the future. I'd suggest editing it to salvage it rather than closing / deleting it.